# AE: Particle Emitter Sourcing Multiple Sprites/Layers (Particular)

Tags: adobe-after-effects

Looked it up on [The Cow](http://forums.creativecow.net/thread/2/948784), but the answer was very vague so I'm probably not doing it right:

I have about 200 icons I want to randomly disperse amongst the comp and have move organically.  How can I use particular to have the particles use multiple sources / layers / sprites, so we can see all of the icons using only one emitter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Woah that Cow link is intense! An idea:

Arrange your "basic" grid using [Gridder](http://aescripts.com/gridder/)
Push everything around a bit to get an "organic" feel
Try wiggling each layer's position—maybe using wiggle(0.25,50)

Or whoops I totally missed the Particular question. Create a comp 200 frames long, have each icon be one frame long (so when you RAM preview this it speeds through everything crazy-like [this is for Particular btw]). Then in your Particular settings… image attached![image]